# Change Icon colour once clicked

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I would like to make the favourit icon change colour once clicked. I tried so many things and still can't seem to figure out how.Please help.

```
 Positioned(
            bottom: 70,
            left: 80,
            right: 60,
            child: Row(
              children: [
                AppButtons(size: 45,
                  color: Color(0xFF989acd),
                  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                  borderColor: Color(0xFF989acd),
                  isIcon:true,
                  icon: Icons.favorite_border,),
                SizedBox(width: 15,),
                RespButton(
                  isResponsive: true,

                ),
              ],

            ))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
bool isFavourite = false;

 Positioned(
            bottom: 70,
            left: 80,
            right: 60,
            child: Row(
              children: [
                AppButtons(size: 45,
                  color: isFavourite ? Color('Other color') : Color(0xFF989acd),
                  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                  borderColor: Color(0xFF989acd),
                  isIcon:true,
                  icon: Icons.favorite_border,),
                SizedBox(width: 15,),
                RespButton(
                  isResponsive: true,

                ),
              ],

            ))
```

```
onPressed: () {
   SetState(() {
     isFavourite = !isFavourite;
   }
}
```